# 'The thing you want to instantiate is null' - unity error when instantiating

Tags: c#, unity

I have a Game Object called 'car' in my Assets folder. I have this code in C# unity to instantiate it.

```
GameObject car; 

    void Start () {

        Vector3 position = new Vector3(5, 5, 5);

        GameObject newGameObject = Instantiate(car);

        newGameObject.transform.position = position;

    }
```

And I get this error - '**the thing you want to instantiate is null**'

What might be the problem ?

Comment: It should be pretty clear.. you're trying to instantiate `null`.. so `car` is null.. you need to assign something to `car`? (Drag your asset to the car property in the inspector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GameObject` car is not set to anything. That means it's `null`. This is exactly what the error message is telling you. Just because you happen to have a prefab named 'car' in your Assets folder doesn't mean you can name a variable `car` and expect Unity to know you're talking about the same thing.

See [my answer to your other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/97375/7191) to learn one way to instantiate a prefab.